# Nginx proxy cache always x-cache-status: MISS

Tags: nginx

My nginx cache does not work. I have followed some answers by still not work. Could anybody help me?

I have ignored the headers: cache-control, Set-Cookies, but not work.

**My cached url is**: 
https://p.rmiao.top/proxy/bing/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=2

**My Request Headers**:

```
:authority: p.rmiao.top
:method: GET
:path: /proxy/bing/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=2
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,zh-TW;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
origin: https://www.cnblogs.com
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://www.cnblogs.com/woshimrf/p/java-list-distinct.html
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

**My Response Headers**:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Cache-Control, reqid, nid, host, x- real-ip, x-forwarded-ip, event-type, event-id, accept, content-type
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.cnblogs.com
access-control-max-age: 2592000
cache-control: public, max-age=604800
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 771
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 09:13:24 GMT
server: nginx/1.12.2
status: 200
x-cache-status: MISS
```

**My nginx configure**:

```html
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=bing_cache:10m max_size=1g inactive=48h use_temp_path=off;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  p.rmiao.top;

    location ^~/proxy/bing/ {

        proxy_cache bing_cache;
        proxy_ignore_headers   vary X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control  Set-Cookie;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_hide_header      Cache-Control;
        proxy_hide_header      p3p;
        proxy_hide_header      server;
        proxy_hide_header      date;
        proxy_hide_header      x-msedge-ref;
        proxy_hide_header      vary;
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

        valid_referers none blocked *.cnblogs.com server_names ~\.rmiao\.;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
         return 403;
        }

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' "true";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Cache-Control, reqid, nid, host, x-real-ip, x-forwarded-ip, event-type, event-id, accept, content-type';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 2592000;
        add_header 'Cache-Control' "public, max-age=604800";

        if ( $request_method = "OPTIONS" ) {
          return 204;
        }

        rewrite ^/proxy/bing/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass https://cn.bing.com;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/p.rmiao.top/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/p.rmiao.top/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by restart nginx service.
I guess proxy_cache_path config need to restart to be in use, and nginx -s reload may not work.
Hope this helpful.